# HttpResponseMessage.Content.Headers ContentDisposition is null

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

When downloading a file with HttpClient, I'm downloading first the headers and then the content. When headers are downloaded, I can see Headers collection on the Content property of HttpResponseMessage, but when accessing it through ContentDisposition on Headers, get null
[image: screenshot]

Why this is happening? Fiddler shows headers are fine...

Code:

```
var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri, 
HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
```

## Update 1

It looks like this class is following Content-Disposition implementation outlined in [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) and fails to handle Content-Disposition implementation update [RFC 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266). RFC 2616 defines `filename` parameter value to be a *quoted-string*, where update RFC 6266 just states it should be *value*.

### RFC 2616 Grammar

```
content-disposition = "Content-Disposition" ":"
                          disposition-type *( ";" disposition-parm )
    disposition-type = "attachment" | disp-extension-token
    disposition-parm = filename-parm | disp-extension-parm
    filename-parm = "filename" "=" quoted-string
    disp-extension-token = token
    disp-extension-parm = token "=" ( token | quoted-string )
```

### RFC 6266 Grammar

```
content-disposition = "Content-Disposition" ":"
                        disposition-type *( ";" disposition-parm )

 disposition-type    = "inline" | "attachment" | disp-ext-type
                     ; case-insensitive
 disp-ext-type       = token

 disposition-parm    = filename-parm | disp-ext-parm

 filename-parm       = "filename" "=" value
                     | "filename*" "=" ext-value

 disp-ext-parm       = token "=" value
                     | ext-token "=" ext-value
 ext-token           = <the characters in token, followed by "*">
```

where `ext-value   = <ext-value, defined in [RFC5987], Section 3.2>`

### Examples

Working case

[image: Working case]

Failing case

[image: Failing case]

## Update 2

Opened a [ticket](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/813392/httpresponsemessage-content-headers-contentdisposition-is-null) with MS connect.

## Update 3

Microsoft has acknowledged that [this is a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/813392/httpresponsemessage-content-headers-contentdisposition-is-null) and will fix it.

Comment: The bug link in **update 3** no longer points to the bug. Can OP or someone please fix it?

Comment: @P5Coder Microsoft Connect has been retired and replaced with Microsoft Collaborate without bothering to redirect links. If you still need the link, suggest to ping Microsoft support to help out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the trailing ; in the content-disposition header

```
        [Fact]
        public void ParseContentDispositionHeader()
        {
            var value = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse("attachment; filename=GeoIP2-City_20140107.tar.gz");
            Assert.Equal("GeoIP2-City_20140107.tar.gz",value.FileName);
        }
```

If I add the semi-colon the parsing will fail.  If you look at the RFC6266 grammar, the semi-colon is only supposed to precede the parameter.

Comment: That is correct. Saying that, all major browsers handle that semi-colon correctly by downloading file with the right name.

Comment: @Sean I wonder if a messagehandler could be created that would strip off any trailing semi-colon.  Not sure if you can get at the underlying unprocessed string.

Comment: I have contacted the site that causes the issue, but realistically. I've also yet to hear from MS connect for this issue. They could push back, or alternatively, could parse content disposition header ignoring semi-colon. Also, when file is quoted (RFC 2616 spec), they shouldn't be giving back a name id double-quotes to be backwards compatible.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you - finding this definitely helped me. For the benefit of others, here is my workaround (as apparently this is **still** a thing today???)

I am in a somewhat controlled environment, so the following code assumes:

- Only one Content-Disposition Header
- The tag is in the format: `inline; "filename";`

This will reset the response's ContentDisposition header, so subsequent code works seamlessly:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
if (response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition == null)
{
  IEnumerable<string> contentDisposition;
  if (response.Content.Headers.TryGetValues("Content-Disposition", out contentDisposition))
  {
   response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(contentDisposition.ToArray()[0].TrimEnd(';').Replace("\"",""));
  }
}
```

Comment: It might not be a thing, but still has to be referenced outside the normal header list. Thanks for your example.