# Download A Non-Directed File With C# In WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, download

I have a small problem and I can not figure out how to solve my problem.
I need to download a file from a site in my WPF application, but my problem is i can't access direct link of file because the file is updated daily and the URL respond different file each day. link is correct and i can download in IDM or any web browser, but when I use C# WPF classes like WebClient, it download something else and when I open the file with office it says that file is corrupted. can anyone offer me how to download my excel file from this link using C# in WPF?

Here is [the link](http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0)

Also another problem is I don't know respond file's name, is it possible to figure out the file name too ?

I will appreciate any response, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, the server is not respecting the Accept-Encoding header sent by the request. It just always sends the response with gzip encoding. I was able to download the file sucessfully with HttpClient, once I set AutomaticDecompression to GZip.

```
static void Main()
{
    var task = DownloadFileAsync("http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0");
    task.Wait();

}

static async Task DownloadFileAsync(string url)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip });

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

    // Get the file name from the content-disposition header.
    // This is nasty because of bug in .net: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008499/httpresponsemessage-content-headers-contentdisposition-is-null
    string fileName = response.Content.Headers.GetValues("Content-Disposition")
        .Select(h => Regex.Match(h, @"(?<=filename=).+$").Value)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .Replace('/', '_');

    using (FileStream file = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        await response.Content.CopyToAsync(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my testing that line took a few seconds to execute. How long did you wait for it to finish?

Comment: Very strange. Are you hitting some sort of api limit from your ip address? I just tried it again and it works; although I did notice the file name has forward-slashes in it. Those should be replaced.

Comment: I add configure await (.ConfigureAwait(false)) to the getAsync and now pass this part but stuck in using file part !!! do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at the http headers that the server sends back:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: *
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MarketWatchPlus-1393/4/25.xlsx
Content-Length: 77100
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Date: Tue, 15 Jul 2014 20:59:46 GMT
Expires: Tue, 15 Jul 2014 21:00:44 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Jul 2014 20:59:44 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Notice how it says `gzip` there. I renamed the file to .gz and unzipped it, looks fine then. Looks that while web browsers sort that out by themselves, the `WebRequest` classes do not.

To answer your second question, the file name is in the headers as well.