# HttpClient.getAsync(URL) Hanged And Don't Reply

Tags: c#, wpf, download, httpclient

I have a strange problem, I need to download a file form [this URL](http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0) in my WPF application. Content of file is a excel file which is compressed. I used code below to download the file but the code stuck in line : await client.getAsync(URL) and I don't know why ! Same code executed well in another system. Can you help me what should I do to get answer well ?

```
static void Main()
{
    var task =     DownloadFileAsync("http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0");
    task.Wait();

}

static async Task DownloadFileAsync(string url)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression =     DecompressionMethods.GZip });

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

    // Get the file name from the content-disposition header.
    // This is nasty because of bug in .net:         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008499/httpresponsemessage-content-headers-        contentdisposition-is-null
    string fileName = response.Content.Headers.GetValues("Content-Disposition")
        .Select(h => Regex.Match(h, @"(?<=filename=).+$").Value)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .Replace('/', '_');

    using (FileStream file = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        await response.Content.CopyToAsync(file);
    }
}
```

If there is another way to download this file and get the name of file or a way to correct this code I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is because of deadlock.

Configure the awaiter so that it would not continue back to the original context until the task is complete:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);

await response.Content.CopyToAsync(file).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: thanks a lot , now I stuck in another place, in this line : using (FileStream file = File.Create(fileName)) !!! what's wrong with it ? can I use this methods without await and async ?

Comment: If the error you get is still the same, I would recommend you to try splitting the above 2 async calls into 2 different methods since the 2nd call depends on the output of the 1st one. Then you could coordinate it in your caller method.